# how to start fresh and add custom backgrounds

Tags: media, theming

I am completely new to Drupal 7 and have searched the web hard for a good tutorial that teaches me how to add a custom background to Drupal sites, but to no avail.

I have a Drupal 7 multi-site set-up and I am just trying to change the background image of the Bartik theme to a custom image.

In my project directory I have the following folders:

```
mysite/files
mysite/modules
mysite/themes
mysite/tmp
mysite/settings.php
mysite/default.settings.php
```

Could someone please tell me a way to create a custom background, exclusively, for the site "mysite" without editing any of the core files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a folder called "myTheme" in `sites/all/themes`
2. Create a file in that new folder called "myTheme.info"
3. Copy the sample .info from below into the info file
4. Now create a folder in your theme called "css"
5. Now copy `style.css` from Bartik's css folder into your css folder
6. Now change the background using CSS
7. Any other changes you want to make? Copy from bartik into your theme folder, make the change

**Sample info file:**

```
name = My Theme
description = My theme is amazing
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate
base theme = bartik
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the prompt response. I have done what you detailed above and added the following code to style.css in mysite/themes/css/ - "body {
  background-image:url('../img/globe_connect.jpg);
}" However, it is not changing the default Bartik background. Did I do something wrong or miss a step? I assume this file is not being loaded properly when I load up my page. Thanks.

Comment: Did you change your theme to "myTheme" in the site building, appearance section? This doesn't change bartik, it creates a new theme that's based on bartik.

Comment: Also, I believe it should by in `mysite/themes/myTheme/css` Your files should all be in `mysite/themes/myTheme`. That's your new theme.

Comment: I have changed my directory setup to have style.css in /themes/my_theme/css and the image in /themes/my_theme. The css code is now: body { background-image:url('../img/globe_connect.jpg); } but still no background image is showing. I am using drupal on WAMP. Sorry if I am making stupid mistakes, but this is the first time I have been asked to design a website. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did you actually change the theme to "my theme" ?

Comment: hi jonathan, i redid everything and did exactly as you said without making any modifications of my own. sites/all/themes/myTheme and in here i have myTheme.info and style.css in css folder and myImage.png in myTheme. it still isn't showing up. i cleared the cache i cleaned out everything, but still not showing.

Comment: I meant in the Drupal UI, not in the code or the folders. Like yoursite.com/admin/appearance/list does your theme show up there? Did you enable it?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, after some tweaking i was able to it to show. thank you for your patience and help

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working.